# How to use make "using" keyword within a method to accept it as class level

Tags: c++, c++14

I am trying to create an api which includes a class which will take a vector of arbitrary data type and "retrieve" it as it is. My main goals are

1. While creating the class, user (who is using the api) need to
   mention the datatype.
2. While retrieving the vector, user should not mention the data type. For Ex: A huge such collection of vectors and the program
   which uses this api to output them in a csv. I will just call a
   retrieval method of each class and it will return me a vector and I
   will print in csv format into a file.

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
typedef void* handle;

class p{

    public:
        template<typename T>
        void initialize(std::vector<T> p){
            typeC = T;
            h = &p;
        }

        auto returnVec(){

            return *(reinterpret_cast<std::vector<typeC *>>(h));
        }

    private:
        using typeC = int ;
        handle h;
};


int main(){
    std::vector<std::string>v{"Hare","Krishna"};
    p i;
    i.initialize<std::string>(v);
    std::cout<<i.returnVec()[0];
}
```

Now, I am able to store the vector but for retrieving, reinterpret cast should need to know the data type. So I thought If I can use the `using` keyword to store the data type, I can later use it within reinterpret_cast to return a vector. But I am unable to do so. I can solve this issue if:

1. I can somehow make this `using typeC = T` statement affect at
   class level so that while calling the `returnVec()` the typeC still
   exists as a datatype.
2. Somehow store the data type through a
   variable.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This is too much info. Have you tried declaring the type alias above the point of usage? Also, reinterpret_casting to a vector? That seems very very gross.

Comment: Why do not you make the whole  class templated by T?

Comment: Perhaps a use case for [std::any](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)? It looks to me that you are trying to implement a similar functionality. If you can't use C++17 I think you can try Boost where it came from.

Comment: @DeiDei I am using a reinterpret_cast so that I can use a handle . And if I use `using typeC  =T` it will be restricted to the member function only (That's what my knowledge says, may be I am wrong)

Comment: @Eugene If I make the whole class as template, I cannot create a collection which keeps these classes in map or unordered_map.

Comment: @TheVee I can use std::any or Boost::any but to retrieve them I need to use `std::any_cast<data_type>(var)` so here also I need to have information about the datatype.

Comment: Changing a typedef or a return type of a function or a type of variable when defined (for storing the result) at run time goes against basically all of C++ type system. You'll need to define an abstract superclass for all vectors and subclass wrappers of `std::vector` to that, so that they can all be stored as pointers to a common type.

Comment: @TheVee I can make a member function which accepts an ostream. I also want to extend this project to create dataframe in c++. Somewhat like in R or pandas(python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a function return a different `std::vector<T>` each time, and you certainly can't make a `typedef` dynamically. It's a part of the static declaration of the class: if you bundle it in a precompiled object, for example, other compilation units *must* be able to know what `p::typeC` is. It just won't go in this way in any modification so I'll take the question more broadly.

A way out would be to create a common superclass for the different vectors. Of course you can't change the definition of a `std::vector`, but you can define your own which behaves just like it and derives from whatever you want. Try something along these lines:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class AbstractVector {
  public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const AbstractVector& vector) {
      return vector.print(os);
    }

    // other interface fns

    virtual ~AbstractVector() { }

  private:
    virtual std::ostream& print(std::ostream&) const = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class MyVector : public AbstractVector, public std::vector<T> {
  public:
    using std::vector<T>::vector;

    std::ostream& print(std::ostream& os) const override {
      for(auto& x : *this)
        os << x << ' ';
      return os;
    }
};

int main() {
  AbstractVector* av = new MyVector<float>{1.5, 2.5};
  std::cout << *av << '\n';
  delete av;

  av = new MyVector<char>{'a', 'c', 'e'}; // same variable, now it has chars!
  std::cout << *av << '\n'; // but in the "retrieval" I don't need to mention anything extraordinary
  delete av;
}
```

Now you can have your map store those (ideally in form of `unique_ptr`s or `shared_ptr`s) instead of `std::vector`s.

One downside of this is that `std::vector` does not have a virtual destructor, so if one would think that `MyVector` IS-A vector and assigned a new instance to a `std::vector<>*`, deletion would cause trouble. A more proper way would be to make the inheritance `protected` and re-expose all interface you'll need. But it's a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is store a vector or an arbitrary container for that matter in your class there are two ways to do this:

```
template<class Container>
class P {
    Container c;
};

//usage
P<std::vector<int>> obj1;
```

If you want to further split the vector data structure and its templated type you could do as such:

```
template<class T, template <class , class> class Container>
class P {
     using typeC = Container<T, std::allocator<T>>;
     typeC c;

     const typeC& returnVec() const;

};

//usage
P<int, std::vector> obj2;
```